# what are the different pen styles in qt stylesheets

Tags: qt, qt4, qtstylesheets

I'v only seen "solid" in use everywhere.

Is there any way to draw dashed line borders around widgets using qt stylesheets?

I'v tried looking through the designer, and I can see the different pen styles in QPen, but the stylesheet equivalents of those remain unfound.

Where/What would the complete list of these be?

EDIT:

I made a mess with the question, I didn't specify enough. I wanted to know the syntax for the different edge and fill styles I can use. But the linked Page contains everything:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Gradients, transparency values for colors, pen styles.. the works.

This documentation is way better than the 4.8.4 one I have on my computer, and it even seems to work. (Even though it's for version 5.x)

Comment: [List of property types](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-property-types). Check the border style part.

Comment: Thanks, that gives a bit more to work with. There are QLinearGradient as well as a few others too. I'd like to know the entire list of pen styles I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylesheet border-style is almost the same as in CSS3.

Take a look here: [CSS border-style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) and here: [Qt Style Sheet: border-style](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#border-style)

Comment: The second link contains everything I need. I'm still using 4.8.4 and the documentation on this version is somewhat lacking.